# Get a custom product meta to show up in order items post meta

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom product meta "zoho_id" https://ibb.co/F4M6gSh. I would like to have that meta show up in the order items post meta https://ibb.co/rsVTHxV to use it in Integromat. I tried this code by I got the ID in the order meta not post items and its value was "data". How can I make each product shows that meta in order?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'pd_number_order_meta_data', 10, 3 );
function pd_number_order_meta_data( $item_id, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $zohoid = get_post_meta( $cart_item[ 'product_id' ], 'zoho_id', true );
    if( ! empty($zohoid) )
        wc_update_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'zoho_id', $zohoid );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it https://ibb.co/st6fcDH by the below code from [Pass custom product meta data to the order in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569890/pass-custom-product-meta-data-to-the-order-in-woocommerce-3)

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_file_type_as_order_item_meta', 20, 4);
function save_file_type_as_order_item_meta($item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order) {
    if ( $cost_centre = $values['data']->get_meta('zoho_id') ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( '_zoho_id', $cost_centre ); // Save as order item (visble on admin only)
    }
}
```